# How can i check if gnupg is installed on ubuntu and run a shell script to install it if it is not installed?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, gnupg

```
#! /bin/bash


if which gnupg >/dev/null; then 
    echo "Installed"
else
    echo "Not installed" #If not installed

echo "Installing..."
sudo apt-get install gnupg #installation

fi
```

Do you have any idea? when i run this, it shows that is not installed but it tries to update it. And as a result it says : gnupg is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.

Comment: Sounds like your if statement may be flawed then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to look for `gpg` (the actual executable name), not `gnupg` (the package name). This should solve the problem.

```
if which gpg >/dev/null; then 
    echo "Installed"
# ...
fi
```

Comment: the same problem continues.

Comment: if you type `gpg --version` in a terminal, does it display some GnuPG related messages, or does it display an error (e.g. command not found)?